# how do you make a dropdown menu appear with "@" in text field like in discord

Tags: javascript, text, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, textbox

Just like the title says, how do you make a dropdown appear when you type a certain character, like '@', in a text field?

I've seen methods like using a regex or adjusting an autocomplete function but it doesn't seem right. Maybe I'm wrong. I would appreciate the help!

code snippets preferably in javascript please but doesn't have to be.

Comment: keydown/keyup/keypress events

Comment: thanks for the recommendation! it works! little caveat is that, in discord, if you place your cursor right after the symbol a dropdown menu will also appear. Do you have any recommendations for that?